# WinEdt 11: a button that sends you into the dvi-file at the place where your cursor in the tech-file is

Tags: winedt

I am not a programmer, so I apologize for describing the situation in the words of a user.

I installed WinEdt 11, and I see that for some reason there is no button here, which in the old versions of winedt threw you into the dvi-file at the place where you had the cursor in the tech-file. How can I get this button back?

Or is it possible to replace this button with some other one?

[image: Here is what I see in the menu]

Comment: WinEdt provides several alternative tool bars. See section 2.4 of the [QuickGuide](https://www.winedt.com/doc/QuickGuide.pdf).

Comment: @cabohah I am trying to switch settings in Options -> Toolbar, but I don't see differences. Nothing changes. I would like to have the second variant of the toolbar as it is presented in this QuickGuide, but I don't see how this is to be done.

Comment: Have you tried out, if forward search is available with your document by clicking to the left margin in front of a source line? Sorry, I've not used WinEdt for years. So I cannot tell you more than the QuickGuide.

Comment: @cabohah excuse me, I feel like a peasant in a city, what is the source line?

Comment: look if in the menu the entry TeX->dvi->dvi search work (it probably need that at the bottom, in the status line, there is somewhere a `--src`. But I haven't used a dvi for years, so I have no idea if it still works. Why don't you use pdf?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer you know, I don't see this entry TeX->dvi->dvi search. Is this in WinEdt?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer actually, I don't even see the button for compilation the tex-file.

Comment: yes that is in winedt:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/leRj8.png

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I added the sreen of what I see in menu, there is no the item "Tex".

Comment: load in options>configurations the configuration for your tex system.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I tried to change settings in options->configurations, and it turned out that if I click "Default (Auto-detect)", then the menu changes and this item "Tex" appears. And the dvi-preview works now!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer so this problem with the preview diasppeared! Thank  you!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer however the second problem still remains:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/689949/winedt-11-the-lines-are-too-long?noredirect=1#comment1711972_689949