# WinEdt 11: the lines are too long

Tags: winedt

In my WinEdt 11 in tex-file, the lines are very long, they go far off the screen, and I have to move the cursor to the right for some time to see what is written there. In older versions of WinEdt, there was a setting that allowed you to adjust the length of the lines, so that a long line would automatically turn into several short lines that fit on the screen. I don't remember where this setting was, can you help me to find it?

[image: Here is the screenshot of my editor window]

[image: Here are my wrapping settings]

P.S. I tried different wrapping settings, the proplem remains.

Comment: AFAIR (but I've not used WinEdt for years) it depends also on using Line or Block mode. In Line mode Wrap should be available via the status line. If Wrap is switched of, there is an `X` before `Indent`. Click to the `X`. If `Block` mode is active, first switch to `Line` mode. See also the preferences in section 1.3 of [the quick guide](https://www.winedt.com/doc/QuickGuide.pdf).

Comment: @cabohah I am afraid, this needs to be translated into the language of dummies. I am not a programmer, I don't understand these explanations.

Comment: Do you know options → preferences? Do you know the status line of WinEdt?

Comment: @cabohah yes options → preferences - I see this. What status line is - I actually don't know, excuse me for my ignorance.

Comment: And can you see the wrapping tabular in the preferences dialog? Have you enabled wrapping as shown in the referenced section of the quick quick guide?

Comment: The status line is the bottom element of the WinEdt window, that as last element shows the name of the file. There are other information like line number, Indent/Overwrite *and* Wrap/X *and* Block/Line.

Comment: Ah, yes I see the status line at the bottom!

Comment: @cabohah excuse me what is "wrapping tabular in the preferences dialog" - is still unclear for me.

Comment: The `Preferences` dialog has several tabs. One is titled `Wrapping`. See Figure 1.2 in section 1.3 of the QuickGuide, which I've already linked above.

Comment: @cabohah Ah, yes, I see this Wrapping! What should I change on this page?

Comment: I tried to change the number in the window "Fixed right margin" (initially it was 78, I put 30), but this didn't help.

Comment: As already told: Try the same settings as shown in the QuickGuide. Sorry, I cannot help any more. Please add at least a screenshot of your wrapping settings and a screenshot of the editor window including the status bar. So *others* would be able to compare them with their own settings. And maybe *someone else* can tell you what to change. I could only compare with the settings of the QuickGuide.

Comment: enable wrap (at the bottom of the window)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer do you mean uncheck? This doesn't help...

Comment: @UlrikeFischer excuse me, I understood at last! It was necessary to click at the item "wrap" at the bottom! Yes, this works!